# npm registry change - Still some libraries being downloaded from the old registry.

Tags: node.js, npm, registry

I'm working behind a proxy which is blocking the default npm registry `https://registry.npmjs.org` . I managed to change it to a European mirror which is `https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry` which is luckily not blocked .

The problem described in the title , some libraries still being downloaded from the old registry . Any suggestion ?

> **Correct :**
>   14 http fetch GET 200 https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/tar-pack 1141ms
>   15 http fetch GET 200 https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/validate-npm-package-name 1141ms
>   16 silly pacote range manifest for tar-pack@^3.4.0 fetched in 1141ms
>   17 silly resolveWithNewModule tar-pack@3.4.1 checking installable status
>   18 silly pacote range manifest for validate-npm-package-name@^3.0.0 fetched in 1141ms
>   19 silly resolveWithNewModule validate-npm-package-name@3.0.0 checking installable status
>   20 http fetch GET 200 https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/hyperquest 1156ms
>   21 silly pacote range manifest for hyperquest@^2.1.2 fetched in 1156ms
>   22 silly resolveWithNewModule hyperquest@2.1.3 checking installable status
>   23 http fetch GET 200 https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/tmp 1156ms
>   24 http fetch GET 200 https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/chalk 1219ms
>
> **Unexpected:** 862 silly pacote trying ansi-regex@https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-2.1.1.tgz by hash: sha1-w7M6te42DYbg5ijwRorn7yfWVN8=
>   863 silly extract ansi-styles@2.2.1
>   864 silly pacote trying ansi-styles@http://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles/-/ansi-styles-2.2.1.tgz by hash: sha1-tDLdM1i2NM914eRmQ2gkBTPB3b4=
>   865 silly extract balanced-match@1.0.0
>   866 silly pacote trying balanced-match@https://registry.npmjs.org/balanced-match/-/balanced-match-1.0.0.tgz by hash: sha1-ibTRmasr7kneFk6gK4nORi1xt2c=
>   867 silly extract buffer-from@0.1.2

Comment: I just faced the same problem. It got it fixed after I explicitly set the registry again `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`.
I also cleared the cache and remove the `package-lock.json` by running `npm cache clean -f` and `rm -rf package-lock.json`

Answer (score 0):

After couple of days of investigations , I found a work-around solution : I created a proxy PHP script which will be a wrapper for the main registry `https://registry.npmjs.org` and hosted it somewhere , and defined it as my registry server .

`npm config set registry YOUR_PROXY_HOSTED_PATH/proxy/`

**Proxy Script**

```
<?php
$url=$_GET['url'];
if($url){
$file = file_get_contents('https://registry.npmjs.org/'.$url);
//Locating and Replacing
$file = str_replace('https://registry.npmjs.org/','YOUR_PROXY_HOSTED_PATH/index.php?url=',$file);
die($file);
}
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^proxy/([^/]+) /index.php?url=$1 [NC]
```